# Redirect from an HTML page to another page to a title

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

Is it possible to set up a button link to redirect to another page to a title?

For example in menu I have page "Realised projects" and want to redirect to page "Welcome" where I have my portfolio with title "Realised projects". Is it possible to do it with script that Im using now?

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){location.href="http://example.com/alternate_url.html"} , 0);
</script>
```

I need something like this but for redirect after load the page: `<a href="http://example.com/alternate_url.html" title="test">test</a>`

The question is little bit tricky. But I am using website builder that is shitty af and wont lt me edit the button code, and let me edit only html body script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [use this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

like

```html
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){location.replace("http://example.com/alternate_url.html");} , 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked :)

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){location.href="http://example.com/alternate_url.html",title="test"} , 0);
</script>

<h2 id="test">Title</h2>
```